# Interactive scraping using Flask and Scrapy

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Flask and Scrapy for scraping results from websites. Here, Flask web page is capable of taking input URL to be scraped and then starts crawling. Upto this, everything is fine.

Now, i want to enable this Flask web page to take HTML Tags (which contains some information of an item to be scraped) as input, and based on input tags results should be scraped.

In short, User can decide which items should be scrapped i.e. items should be chosen dynamically.Provide me with some ideas, how can i pass these tags to set of items to be scraped in Item Class???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you could pass along a command line argument property when you start the crawl. In this property you can define the tag to scrape for example.

Then it depends on what you want to achieve: modifying the `Rule` when you scrape or just which tags to select in the `parse_items` function.

Or you can select everything but filter the results when the `item` is processed in your pipeline.

To run the spider with this property you could call it like this:

```
command = "scrapy crawl newFlaskSpider1 -a start_url=" + request.form['url'] + ' -s PROPERTY_NAME=VALUE'
```

As for the [spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.settings) or [crawler](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler.settings) you can access the `settings` propery as it is in the docs -- and this at every stage you want to add your filter.

**UPDATE**

To access the `settings` in the `parse_items` function you can utilize the following:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    if self.settings['MY_PROPERTY']:
        print self.settings['MY_PROPERTY']
```

Then you can start the application with:

```
command = "scrapy crawl newFlaskSpider1 -a start_url=" + request.form['url'] + ' -s MY_PROPERTY="user entered value"'
```

**Update 2**

The wood-cutter solution would be something like this:

```
response.xpath("//*[contains(.,{0})]".format(self.settings['MY_PROPERTY'])).extract()
```

However this extracts everything because of the `*` in the XPath expression. It is a very good practice to reduce the amount of the possible tags. For example tags with `a`:

```
response.xpath("//a[contains(.,{0})]".format(self.settings['MY_PROPERTY'])).extract()
```

I hope you have now the hang of it. Naturally you can use multiple properties (or a dictionary as a value with some extra coding) and you can format your XPath string as you like.

**Update 3**

To use dynamic items with Scrapy (dynamic means the fields are not known when you write the application -- like in your case) you can take a look at the [ScrapyDynamicItems project](https://github.com/WilliamKinaan/ScrapyDynamicItems/blob/master/DynamicItemsScrapy/DynamicItemsScrapy/items.py). Using a dynamic item you can define a field on-the-fly while parsing and then you are able to export it at the end -- without even knowing the name of the field when you export it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and valuable response. But, how to use this PROPERTY_NAME inside the parse_item class to parse the item????

Comment: one more thing, lets suppose this is the link to be scrapped [http://jobs.placementindia.com/lucknow], and user enters tag name as Job Title ; then how i search for html tag having job title and change xpath dynamically???? Actually, this is what i really want. Please, provide some idea to deal with this issue.

Comment: There is a confusion, how this PROPERTY_NAME be incorporated in StackItem(scrapy.Items) class ???

Comment: Updated with an example for your XPath question. Could you elaborate what you mean by "be incorporated in StackItem(scrapy.Items) class ???" ?

Comment: Thanks.
i mean, items to be scrapped should be listed in items.py or some class like stackItem(). my question is how to add the item entered by user in that item class???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87234/discussion-between-ooorza-and-ghajba).