# How to pass data from a Flask API to a web scraper?

Tags: flask, scrapy

I'm working on an application project that allows the user to get web page search results after entering a set of keywords that will be sent to Ask. For this, I created an api in Flask and scrapy inspired by the following article for the [api](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/integrating-scrapy-with-flask-8611debc4579) . But, the api doesn't work because I can't pass the data used as keywords from my api to my scraper.
Here is my flask api file:

```
import crochet
crochet.setup()

from flask import Flask , render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
import time
import os

# Importing our Scraping Function from the amazon_scraping file

from scrap.askScraping import AskScrapingSpider

# Creating Flask App Variable

app = Flask(__name__)

output_data = []
crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()

# By Deafult Flask will come into this when we run the file
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html") # Returns index.html file in templates folder.


# After clicking the Submit Button FLASK will come into this
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        s = request.form['url'] # Getting the Input Amazon Product URL
        global baseURL
        baseURL = s
        # This will remove any existing file with the same name so that the scrapy will not append the data to any previous file.
        if os.path.exists("<path_to_outputfile.json>"): 
            os.remove("<path_to_outputfile.json>")
        
        return redirect(url_for('scrape')) # Passing to the Scrape function
    

@app.route("/scrape")
def scrape():

    scrape_with_crochet(baseURL="https://www.ask.com/web?q={baseURL}") # Passing that URL to our Scraping Function

    time.sleep(20) # Pause the function while the scrapy spider is running
    
    return jsonify(output_data) # Returns the scraped data after being running for 20 seconds.


@crochet.run_in_reactor
def scrape_with_crochet(baseURL):
    # This will connect to the dispatcher that will kind of loop the code between these two functions.
    dispatcher.connect(_crawler_result, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    
    # This will connect to the ReviewspiderSpider function in our scrapy file and after each yield will pass to the crawler_result function.
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(AskScrapingSpider, category = baseURL)
    return eventual

#This will append the data to the output data list.
def _crawler_result(item, response, spider):
    output_data.append(dict(item))


if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my scraper one

```
import scrapy
import datetime



class AskScrapingSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'ask_scraping'
    def start_requests(self):
        myBaseUrl = ''
        start_urls = []

        def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs): # The category variable will have the input URL.
            self.myBaseUrl = category
            self.start_urls.append(self.myBaseUrl)
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

            custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': 'scrap/outputfile.json', 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT' : 15} # This will tell scrapy to store the scraped data to outputfile.json and for how long the spider should run.

        
            yield scrapy.Request(start_urls, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})
                            
    
    


    def parse(self, response):
         print('url:', response.url)
        
         start_pos = response.meta['pos']
         print('start pos:', start_pos)

         dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')    
        
         items = response.css('div.PartialSearchResults-item')
        
         for pos, result in enumerate(items, start_pos+1):
            yield {
                'title':    result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link::text').get().strip(), 
                'snippet':  result.css('p.PartialSearchResults-item-abstract::text').get().strip(), 
                'link':     result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link').attrib.get('href'), 
                'position': pos, 
                'date':     dt,
            }

        # --- after loop ---
        
         next_page = response.css('.PartialWebPagination-next a')
        
         if next_page:
            url = next_page.attrib.get('href')
            print('next_page:', url)  # relative URL
            # use `follow()` to add `https://www.ask.com/` to URL and create absolute URL
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': pos+1})
```

when I run absolutely no errors. After looking at a user's answer to my question, I changed the code of my scraper as follows but without success because, after passing the data to scrape, I get in my browser at the following url `localhost:5000/scrape` empty brackets `[]` yet the brackets should normally contain the data returned by my scraper :

```
 import scrapy
import datetime



class AskScrapingSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'ask_scraping'
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})

    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': 'scrap/outputfile.json', 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT' : 15}
    def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs):
        self.myBaseUrl = category
        self.start_urls.append(self.myBaseUrl)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
           
                            
    
    


    def parse(self, response):
         print('url:', response.url)
        
         start_pos = response.meta['pos']
         print('start pos:', start_pos)

         dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')    
        
         items = response.css('div.PartialSearchResults-item')
        
         for pos, result in enumerate(items, start_pos+1):
            yield {
                'title':    result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link::text').get().strip(), 
                'snippet':  result.css('p.PartialSearchResults-item-abstract::text').get().strip(), 
                'link':     result.css('a.PartialSearchResults-item-title-link.result-link').attrib.get('href'), 
                'position': pos, 
                'date':     dt,
            }

        # --- after loop ---
        
         next_page = response.css('.PartialWebPagination-next a')
        
         if next_page:
            url = next_page.attrib.get('href')
            print('next_page:', url)  # relative URL
            # use `follow()` to add `https://www.ask.com/` to URL and create absolute URL
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': pos+1})
```

I also replaced in my `main.py` file `crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()` with

```
project_settings = get_project_settings()
crawl_runner = CrawlerProcess(settings = project_settings)
```

and performed the following imports

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
```

but I get when I reload my Flask server the following errors:

```
2022-06-21 11:44:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-06-21 11:44:57 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.4.0, Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.3 3 May 2022), cryptography 37.0.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2022-06-21 11:44:57 [werkzeug] WARNING:  * Debugger is active!
2022-06-21 11:44:57 [werkzeug] INFO:  * Debugger PIN: 107-226-838
2022-06-21 11:44:57 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT': 15}
2022-06-21 11:44:57 [werkzeug] INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2022 11:44:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2022-06-21 11:44:58 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in EventualResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1315, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1325, in mainLoop
    reactorBaseSelf.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 964, in runUntilCurrent
    f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\crochet\_eventloop.py", line 420, in runs_in_reactor
    d = maybeDeferred(wrapped, *args, **kwargs)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 190, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\API\main.py", line 62, in scrape_with_crochet
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(AskScrapingSpider, category = baseURL)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 205, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 238, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 313, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings, init_reactor=True)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 82, in __init__
    default.install()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 194, in install
    installReactor(reactor)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\main.py", line 32, in installReactor
    raise error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError("reactor already installed")
twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed

2022-06-21 11:44:58 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in EventualResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1315, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1325, in mainLoop
    reactorBaseSelf.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 964, in runUntilCurrent
    f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\crochet\_eventloop.py", line 420, in runs_in_reactor
    d = maybeDeferred(wrapped, *args, **kwargs)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 190, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\API\main.py", line 62, in scrape_with_crochet
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(AskScrapingSpider, category = baseURL)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 205, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 238, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 313, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings, init_reactor=True)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 82, in __init__
    default.install()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 194, in install
    installReactor(reactor)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\main.py", line 32, in installReactor
    raise error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError("reactor already installed")
twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed

2022-06-21 11:45:54 [werkzeug] INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2022 11:45:54] "←[32mPOST / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 302 -
2022-06-21 11:45:54 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT': 15}
2022-06-21 11:45:54 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in EventualResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1315, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1325, in mainLoop
    reactorBaseSelf.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 964, in runUntilCurrent
    f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\crochet\_eventloop.py", line 420, in runs_in_reactor
    d = maybeDeferred(wrapped, *args, **kwargs)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 190, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\API\main.py", line 62, in scrape_with_crochet
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(AskScrapingSpider, category = baseURL)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 205, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 238, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 313, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings, init_reactor=True)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 82, in __init__
    default.install()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 194, in install
    installReactor(reactor)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\main.py", line 32, in installReactor
    raise error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError("reactor already installed")
twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed

2022-06-21 11:45:54 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in EventualResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1315, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1325, in mainLoop
    reactorBaseSelf.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 964, in runUntilCurrent
    f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\crochet\_eventloop.py", line 420, in runs_in_reactor
    d = maybeDeferred(wrapped, *args, **kwargs)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 190, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\API\main.py", line 62, in scrape_with_crochet
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(AskScrapingSpider, category = baseURL)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 205, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 238, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 313, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings, init_reactor=True)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 82, in __init__
    default.install()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 194, in install
    installReactor(reactor)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\main.py", line 32, in installReactor
    raise error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError("reactor already installed")
twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed
```

I looked on this stackOverflow  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064850/interactive-scraping-using-flask-and-scrapy) but without success.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't yield

> scrapy.Request

in **init** method.

delete this line:

```
yield scrapy.Request(start_urls, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})
```

and change your **init** method like this:

```
custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': 'scrap/outputfile.json', 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT' : 15}
def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs):
        self.myBaseUrl = category
        self.start_urls.append(self.myBaseUrl)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

it might work.

**update:**

if you want to pass argument in your request, after changing in those lines you can override start_requests() method like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'pos': 0})
```

**update 2:**
if your scrapy spider runs in background of your flask app try this:
write these lines:

```
project_settings = get_project_settings()
crawl_runner = CrawlerProcess(settings = project_settings)
```

instead of:

```
crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()
```

and of course you should import **CrawlerProcess** and **get_project_settings** like this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
```

**update 3:**
I'd wrote some project like this, it was working properly, you can check [this repo](https://github.com/alireza-f/scrapy-flask-digikala)

Comment: I tested your solution but without success, I put more details in my question

Comment: Does Scrapy spider run in the background of your flask app?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, can I have some clearer explanation please?

Comment: I tested the code of your update, but without success and moreover I am now getting errors. More details in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Check my **update 2** code

Comment: That's what I did and that's what gave me the last edited errors in my code unless you want me to show you the whole updated file after reading your answer.

Comment: I want to clarify that I have not created a scrapy project. All the scrapy code for my scraper is in the file mentioned in my question

Comment: Idk why it doesn't work for you. check update 3 repo link.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded your git and didn't proceed to modify any files except, delete your docker files because I don't use it and don't even know what it is, I ran your project with command `python main.py`  but still getting the  [ errors ](https://gist.github.com/gouneken/f165d9b2fef08640ba7633fe99ab0427) : I've   `scrape_with_crochet(category=category)
NameError: name 'category' is not defined `. I don't know if for this to work I have to use docker or does the command I used to run have no problem?